# Detect if (Android) phone encryption is enabled

Tags: android, security, encryption, settings

I want to store data securely in a user friendly way.
As default the data is encrypted and needs a pass phrase to be unlocked. However, if the phone is encrypted and needs a pass phrase to be unlocked this seems redundant and I would like to give the option to turn of application encryption thus avoiding typing in a (new) pass phrase when starting the application.

However - is it possible to detect if phone encryption is enabled? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getStorageEncryptionStatus()` on `DevicePolicyManager` to find out the encryption status of the device.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html)

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see this doesn't require any special permissions, is this correct?

Comment: Oh - I have not implemented it yet. I was just a quick question because it looked like something which might require special permissions or the app to run as a system app.